# Universal covering as a principal $G(\tilde{X})$-bundle

Tags: smooth-manifolds, covering-spaces, principal-bundles

Let $X$ be a manifold and consider the universal covering
$$p:\tilde{X}\longrightarrow X$$
I know that this has a structure as a principal $G(\tilde{X})$-bundle but I can't manage to correctly define trivializations:

Let $U\subset X$ be a neighbourhood such that $p^{-1}(U)$ is a disjoint union of open sets each of which is mapped homemorphically into $U$ by (the restriction of) $p$. Thus the trivialization has to be something like
$$\varphi:\bigcup_{\alpha\in\Sigma}U_\alpha\longrightarrow G(\tilde{X})\times U$$
which (I think) must have the form
$$x\in U_\alpha\longmapsto (f_\alpha,p(x))$$
so the first component depends only on the $U_\alpha$ and the second is always the projection of $x$. My problem is that I don't see how to define this $f_\alpha$, it feels that there is no canonical way of doing it, and I have to make a choice, but I don't see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pick one of the $U_\alpha$; let's say it's $U_1$.  The group $G(\tilde{X})$ acts simply and transitively on the collection of the $U_\alpha$, so for each $\alpha$ there is a unique $g\in G(\tilde{X})$ such that $g(U_1)=U_\alpha$.  You then define $f_\alpha$ to be this $g$.

In other words, once you fix the value of $f_\alpha$ for one particular $\alpha$ however you want to, all the others are uniquely determined by the action of $G(\tilde{X})$.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but how do you define it for a different $U$? Can you just chose arbitrarily every time?

Comment: Yes.  You only need to give a _local_ trivialization, in other words for one $U$ at a time.

Comment: I am still having some trouble with this. I wanted this in order to show that the transition functions are locally constant, with this arbitrary assignation I don't see how to do it, I can certainly do it for each pair, but not for every one at the same time, right?

Comment: If $U_\alpha$ is one of your sheets covering $p^{-1}(U)$ and $V_\beta$ is one of your sheets covering $p^{-1}(V)$, the transition function will be constant on the intersection $U_\alpha\cap V_\beta$.  These sets are open and cover $p^{-1}(U)\cap p^{-1}(V)$, so the transition function is locally constant.

Comment: But transition functions are defined in the intersection $U\cap V$ and not on those, right?

Comment: Er, right, sorry.  The transition function will be constant on the image $p(U_\alpha\cap V_\beta)$, which is open since $p$ is an open map.

Comment: If you only care about manifolds, you can make things simpler by just assuming that you have an open cover by geodesically convex sets.  Then each $U$ is connected, as is the intersection of any two of them.  This guarantees that the sheets over $U$ and the sheets over $V$ must line up perfectly: each sheet over $U$ intersects a unique sheet over $V$.  Then the transition function will actually be constant on $U\cap V$, not just locally constant.

Comment: I see. I am doing this in order to understand the relation between representations of the fundamental group of a manifold, and principal $G$-bundles with flat connections over that manifold. The notes I am using (available online for free here https://goo.gl/iBR9ZK) are a bit dry and I get stuck every two lines, do you know any other reference?